# Ancestry gem rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

So I added the ancestry gem to my rails app. I was using model named aircraft and this had a relationship with my category model. All worked fine when running a seed to create to categories and subcategories in my app.

I then decided to delete my aircraft model name and add a listing model. I done the following steps to delete the aircraft model.

reverted back to the migration. 
rails db:migrate:down VERSION=20180830175747

removed the file then ran the rails destroy model Aircraft

and then had some issues with below error. So I reverted back to my first migration, deleted category model, listing model etc. Removed ancestry gem.

Then started a fresh. All looked good until I try run a seed file then I get the following error.

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `child_ancestry' for "aircraft":String
/Users/bradley/Development/current/global_abx/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Anybody have any clue as to why the child_ancestry still refers to anything related to aircraft??

Thanks a million.

Seed file:

```
aircraft = Category.create(name: 'Aircraft')
aircraft_jets = Category.create(name: 'Jets', parent: 'aircraft')
aircraft_helicopter = Category.create(name: 'Helicopter', parent: 'aircraft')
aircraft_light = Category.create(name: 'Light', parent: 'aircraft')
aircraft_twin_piston = Category.create(name: 'Twin Piston', parent: 'aircraft')
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_ancestry
end
```

Comment: `"aircraft"` in this case is a string. Check your seeds file for that string.

Comment: added seed file. which looks ok no? name is a string in category. My old model was named aircraft. That's why I think it's relating to that somehow even though i've destroyed model, cleared migrations etc. I feel the ancestry gem somewhere is still seeing aircraft model. I'm gonna change text in this seed file see if it still error on string. thanks.

Comment: Post your category model.

Comment: Ah right that's what it is picking up alright. Then this means ancestry is not doing connected to category. Category has_ancestry in model. strange. Was working before changing models.

Comment: I don't really know the ancestry gem that well. But seems like the `parent` association that gets defined by `has_ancestry` is expecting a `Category` object. Not a string. I think you simple need to remove the `'` around `'aircraft'`.

Comment: Oh jaysus! Spot on. That's it. I'm a balloon! Thanks @DickieBoy